# Axis java to wsdl and complexType list

Tags: java, web-services, xsd, wsdl, apache-axis

I'm currently facing a wsdl missmatch between entity and WSDL definition. It seems to ignore a list of complex type. I'm using Axis 2 to generate the WSDL from entities that are generated from an XSD file.

Here is the part of the XSD file :

```
<xs:element name="Funds">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="Fund" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element type="xs:string" name="code" />
                <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Status" />
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
```

This generates the following entities :

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "fund"
})
public static class Funds {

    @XmlElement(name = "Fund")
    @XmlAnyElement(lax=true)
    protected List<Request.Funds.Fund> fund;

    public List<Request.Funds.Fund> getFund() {
        if (fund == null) {
            fund = new ArrayList<Request.Funds.Fund>();
        }
        return this.fund;
    }


    public void setFund(List<Request.Funds.Fund> fund) {
        this.fund = fund;
    }

    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
        "code",
        "status"
    })
    public static class Fund {

        @XmlElement(name = "CODE", required = true)
        protected String code;
        @XmlElement(name = "Status", required = true)
        protected String status;

        public String getCODE() {
            return code;
        }

        public void setCODE(String value) {
            this.code = value;
        }

        public String getStatus() {
            return status;
        }

        public void setStatus(String value) {
            this.status = value;
        }
    }
}
```

This generated code gives the following WSDL :

```
<xs:complexType name="Request_Funds">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="fund" nillable="true" type="xs:anyType"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

The list is typed as anyType so when it is unmarshalled I get the following error :

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl cannot be cast to com.legalsuite.services.start.importxml.Request$Funds$Fund
```

What can I do to avoid this behavior ?

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't declare `Funds` as an `XmlElement`, it's not a part of your WSDL. It's just a container.

I think you should declare `Funds` explicitly so there's no confusion for the WSDL as follow :

```
@XmlElement(name = "Funds")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "Fund"
})
public static class Funds {

    @XmlElement(name = "Fund")
    @XmlAnyElement(lax=true)
    protected List<Request.Funds.Fund> fund;

    public List<Request.Funds.Fund> getFund() {
        if (fund == null) {
            fund = new ArrayList<Request.Funds.Fund>();
        }
        return this.fund;
    }


    public void setFund(List<Request.Funds.Fund> fund) {
        this.fund = fund;
    }

    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
        "code",
        "status"
    })
    public static class Fund {

        @XmlElement(name = "CODE", required = true)
        protected String code;
        @XmlElement(name = "Status", required = true)
        protected String status;

        public String getCODE() {
            return code;
        }

        public void setCODE(String value) {
            this.code = value;
        }

        public String getStatus() {
            return status;
        }

        public void setStatus(String value) {
            this.status = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that and I have the following error: "The annotation @XmlElement is disallowed for this location"

Comment: Did you generate Java classes from XSD ?

Comment: Yes, I generated them from the XSD above

Comment: Then, you should have annotations on class `Funds`. If you do, can you please share what it is ?

Comment: Sorry I've been to hurry and forgot to copy the annotation above the class Funds. I've edited the code and placed them.